# How to use Vlookup in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vlookup through VBA to fetch values across two different workbooks (A,B) and fill some values in a column of workbook A

The important requirment for me is that the search range in workbook B should be dynamic.

Therefore I have already calculated the number of rows of the table in workbook B.

Here is the code I tried to write.It does not compile due to the syntax error inside the Vlookup:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
     Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("M2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-12],[petest.xlsx]Sheet1!A1:"&lrow2,8,FALSE),RC[-1])"
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & lrow)
    Range("M2:M" & lrow).Select
```

Here lrow contains the last column of the table of the first workbook while lrow2 the last column in the second workbook ( the one I am searching into)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line :

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-12],[petest.xlsx]Sheet1!A1:"&lrow2,8,FALSE),RC[-1])"
```

to

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-12],[petest.xlsx]Sheet1!A1:L" & lrow & ",8,FALSE),RC[-1])"
```

This will insert the actual value of lrow into the formula

**UPDATE**

You need to add "L" to the vlookup formula so it has A1:L and not just A1. I have edited the code above. Try that please

Comment: I think the variable is `lrow`.  See the last 2 lines of the code :)

Comment: Hi Nick and thanks for your answer.

I added the code you suggested but now I get error 1004 for this part of the code :
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-12],[petest.xlsx]Sheet1!A1:" & lrow2 & ",8,FALSE),RC[-1])"

Comment: @NicolaBazingaDragoni, change the lrow2 to lrow

Comment: @NicolaBazingaDragoni ok let me test the code. By the way can you post the code you are using to count the rows? i take it you are trying to enter the formula down a column?

Comment: @NicolaBazingaDragoni: Try changing `Sheet1!A1:" & lrow & "` to `Sheet1!A1:J" & lrow & "` You are missing an end column in the table

Comment: @SiddharthRout good point, just edited the answer to add that.